# Why are so many modules initially loaded in CPython?

Tags: python, python-module, cpython

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/toplevel_components.html#complete-python-programs) state:

> A complete Python program is executed in a minimally initialized environment: all built-in and standard modules are available, but none have been initialized, except for `sys` (various system services), `builtins` (built-in functions, exceptions and None) and `__main__`.

This would suggest that only those three modules should be listed as loaded modules with [the following code snippet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys
print(sys.modules.keys())
```

However, running the code snippet using CPython v3.10 ([with -S option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S)) returns the following on my PC:

```
dict_keys(['sys', 'builtins', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_thread', '_warnings', '_weakref', '_io', 'marshal', 'nt', 'winreg', '_frozen_importlib_external', 'time', 'zipimport', '_codecs', 'codecs', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings', 'encodings.utf_8', 'encodings.cp1252', '_signal', '_abc', 'abc', 'io', '__main__'])
```

Why are there 22 extra modules loaded at runtime as compared to the "minimally initialized environment" mentioned in the docs?

I am updating my understanding of CPython's extra loaded modules with my own answer below.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation suggests the output you saw, given that description is for the barest minimum Python that could exist in theory. You likely ran that code through CPython, which provides implementation specific environment, provided by its default import of its `_frozen_importlib`.  Running the same code in the pypy implementation will result in some of the same keys plus certain other ones.

Comment: @metatoaster I have updated the question to specifically ask the reason why CPython requires so many more packages.

Comment: Doubtful you will get a specific answer aside from that being an implementation detail that the documentation does not describe. If this really irks you I'd suggest filing an issue at CPython's [issue tracker](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues).

Comment: Moreover, you can run `python -S -v -c ''` which would print out what gets imported during startup and running an empty Python program.

Answer (score 1):

#### What I have found so far:

The majority of the extra modules are active to provide the `import` keyword functionality, and for text encodings.

- During interpreter initialisation, the import functionality is provided by importing `_frozen_importlib` and `_imp` (during pycore_interp_init, within [init_importlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pylifecycle.c))
- _setup() in importlib's [_bootstrap.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py) then imports `_thread`, `_warnings`, and `_weakref` ***because they are builtin modules that are explicitly imported during bootstrap, and hence not really extra modules***.
- Interpreter initialisation then imports `_frozen_importlib_external` (during init_interp_main, within [init_importlib_external](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pylifecycle.c))
- importlib's [_bootstrap_external.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py) imports four new module dependencies: `_io`, `marshal`, `nt`, and `winreg` packages. If not on Windows, `posix` gets imported rather than `nt` and `winreg`.

  - `_io` is imported ***because it is a builtin module explicitly imported during bootstrap, and hence not really an extra module***.
  - `marshal` is imported ***because it is used to load/dump bytecode from/to .pyc files***.
  - `nt`/`posix` is imported ***because it is used for operating system functions such as reading the current working directory***.
  - `winreg` is imported ***because it is used to find modules declared in the windows registry***.
- As part of importing `_frozen_importlib_external`, the interpreter initialization then imports `zipimport`, presumably to allow for opening zip-format python archives

  - As part of importing [`zipimport`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/zipimport.py), the only new dependency is the `time` module which is imported. The only use is time.mktime() to "convert the date/time values found in the Zip archive to a value that's compatible with the time stamp stored in .pyc files"
- After `_frozen_importlib_external` (and thus after `import` keyword functionality is sorted), the interpreter initialization then imports `encodings`, presumably for decoding source text.

  - `encodings.aliases` is imported ***because it provides a dictionary of names to map to known encodings***.
  - `codecs` is imported as it is a dependency of `encodings`

    - `_codecs` is imported, presumably because it is the C version of `codecs`?
  - `encodings.utf_8` is then imported, presumably because it is the default encoding.
  - Because we are on Windows, `encodings.cp1252` is also imported (`encodings.latin_1` is imported instead if on Linux).
- The interpreter initialization then imports `_signal`, presumably for the interpreter to deal with signal handling.
- `io` is then fully imported, presumably to open source files?

  - `abc` is then imported as it is a dependency on `io`?

    - `_abc` is then imported, presumably because it is the C version of `codecs`?
- (On Linux, `readline` is also imported)

And thus 22 extra 'modules' are loaded when using CPython.